# Building JanusGraph Indexes On Cassandra In Java

Tags: full-text-search, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, java-17

## Problem

What are the next steps to complete [JanusGraph indices](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/)?

I've already tried following line-by-line of the JanusGraph docs;
And tried using closer to source commits `janusGraph` instead of `janusGraphManagement`;
And tried suggestions provided so far; which none have worked yet.

```json
[o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::   Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
```

## Trials

### Try 1

Tried to recreate what I initially made, and a part of the [suggestion to revisit JanusGraph docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/).
The issue with this one is that logs said I didn't have indexes still.
This is what initially got me checking if I was needing `janusGraph.commit()` instead.

#### Logs

```json
...

2023-05-15 09:58:05,984 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-15T14:58:05.984686Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@48b4a043
2023-05-15 09:58:06,047 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 09:58:06,270 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 09:58:06,275 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    drop g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():  0
2023-05-15 09:58:07,020 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 09:58:07,033 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    addVertex g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next(): 1
2023-05-15 09:58:07,046 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.m.GraphIndexStatusWatcher.main] ::   Some key(s) on index _id do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: _id=ENABLED

...

[o.j.g.d.m.GraphIndexStatusWatcher.main] ::  Some key(s) on index _id do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: _id=ENABLED
2023-05-15 09:59:07,520 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.m.GraphIndexStatusWatcher.main] ::   Timed out (PT1M) while waiting for index _id to converge on status(es) [REGISTERED]
2023-05-15 09:59:07,522 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 09:59:07,531 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    awaitGraphIndexStatus g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next(): 1
2023-05-15 09:59:07,627 [INFO] [o.j.g.o.j.IndexRepairJob.Thread-68] ::   Index _id metrics: success-tx: 2 doc-updates: 0 succeeded: 1

...

2023-05-15 09:59:08,297 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.m.ManagementSystem.Thread-51] ::     Index update job successful for [_id]
2023-05-15 09:59:08,299 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 09:59:08,304 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    updateIndex g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Code

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphVertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphIndex;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.SchemaAction;
import org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusReport;
import org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("drop g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphVertex vertex = janusGraph.addVertex("entity");
        vertex.property("_id", "Test1");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("addVertex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id"))
            janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        GraphIndexStatusReport report = ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(janusGraph, "_id").call();
        logger.info("awaitGraphIndexStatus g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphIndex test = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
        janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(test, SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        logger.info("updateIndex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

### Try 2

JanusGraph is telling me I cannot enable index because its installed.
Which JanusGraph should be telling me its registered instead.
Which shouldn't even matter if I'm just doing a basic `awaitGraphIndexStatus()` like the example.
Which wouldn't matter if I knew how to create the index before the vertices existed.

#### Logs

```json
2023-05-12 12:50:04,641 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-12 12:50:04,737 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-12 12:50:05,236 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-12 12:50:05,518 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=4fe054a)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-12 12:50:05,763 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c21084-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-12 12:50:05,786 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-12 12:50:05,823 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-12 12:50:05,861 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=5ac9b054)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-12 12:50:05,880 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-12 12:50:05,998 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-12 12:50:06,026 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-12T17:50:06.025476Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@48b4a043
2023-05-12 12:50:06,086 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-12 12:50:06,344 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-12 12:50:06,353 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    drop g.V().count().next(): 0
2023-05-12 12:50:07,107 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-12 12:50:07,110 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    addVertex g.V().count().next():    1
2023-05-12 12:50:08,197 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-12 12:50:08,202 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    buildIndex g.V().count().next():   1
2023-05-12 12:50:08,209 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-12 12:50:08,212 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    updateIndex g.V().count().next():  1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update action [ENABLE_INDEX] cannot be invoked for index with status [INSTALLED]
    at org.janusgraph.core.schema.SchemaAction.isApplicableStatus(SchemaAction.java:85)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.updateIndex(ManagementSystem.java:864)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.updateIndex(ManagementSystem.java:845)
    at Test12.main(Test12.java:39)
```

#### Code

```java
public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("drop g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphVertex vertex = janusGraph.addVertex("entity");
        vertex.property("_id", "Test1");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("addVertex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("buildIndex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id"), SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("REGISTER_INDEX g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("ENABLE_INDEX g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(janusGraph, "_id").call();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("awaitGraphIndexStatus g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

### Try 3

[Suggestion to revisit JanusGraph docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/), I no longer think the output was a misnomer.
Cleaned up to what it is now.

#### Logs

```json
2023-05-15 11:02:15,142 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-15 11:02:15,230 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-15 11:02:15,853 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-15 11:02:16,152 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=705b0e14)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-15 11:02:16,410 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a856493416-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-15 11:02:16,433 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-15 11:02:16,472 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-15 11:02:16,522 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=1b473c95)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-15 11:02:16,548 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-15 11:02:16,678 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-15 11:02:16,704 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-15T16:02:16.704454Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@74ea46e2
2023-05-15 11:02:16,762 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 11:02:16,989 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 11:02:16,992 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    drop g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():  0
2023-05-15 11:02:17,010 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 11:02:17,014 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    makePropertyKey g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   0
2023-05-15 11:02:17,748 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 11:02:17,759 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    addVertex g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next(): 1
2023-05-15 11:02:17,761 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 11:02:17,764 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    updateIndex g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Code

```java
public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        logger.info("drop g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsPropertyKey("_id"))
            janusGraphManagement.makePropertyKey("_id").dataType(String.class).make();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        logger.info("makePropertyKey g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphVertex vertex = janusGraph.addVertex("entity");
        vertex.property("_id", "Test1");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
        logger.info("addVertex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

### Resources

1. [Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. [Java 11.0.19 (corretto-11)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html)
3. [JanusGraph 1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2)
4. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20)
5. [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
6. [Cassandra:latest [container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)
7. [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final issue was understanding that [`propertyKey` and its `value` have to be supplied](https://discord.com/channels/838910279550238720/1107733782179631185/1107746578124505158).
Thanks again [Stephen Mallette](https://twitter.com/spmallette)!
He provided a [great resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49966807/11705601) from [Jason Plurad](https://twitter.com/pluradj) if you extrapolate more of what you read.

```json
2023-05-15 15:33:56,415 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.b.ReadConfigurationBuilder.main] ::  Set default timestamp provider MICRO
2023-05-15 15:33:56,428 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8564917832-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-15 15:33:56,440 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-15 15:33:56,488 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-15 15:33:56,494 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-15T20:33:56.494323Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@54e7391d
2023-05-15 15:33:56,576 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,599 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,601 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    drop g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():  0
2023-05-15 15:33:56,805 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,806 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    REGISTER_INDEX g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():    0
2023-05-15 15:33:56,961 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,971 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    addVertex g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next(): 1
2023-05-15 15:33:56,972 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,973 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1
2023-05-15 15:33:56,991 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[_id <> null]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,998 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1
2023-05-15 15:33:56,998 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[~label = entity, _id <> null]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-15 15:33:56,999 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1
2023-05-15 15:33:57,000 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next():   1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphVertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Test16 {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        //JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "inmemory").open();
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        logger.info("drop g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id"))
            janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        logger.info("REGISTER_INDEX g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        JanusGraphVertex vertex = janusGraph.addVertex("entity");
        vertex.property("_id", "Test1");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        logger.info("addVertex g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        logger.info("g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").count().next());
        logger.info("g.V().has(\"_id\").count().next();:\t" + g.V().has("_id").count().next());
        logger.info("g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").has(\"_id\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").has("_id").count().next());
        logger.info("g.V().hasLabel(\"entity\").has(\"_id\", \"Test1\").count().next():\t" + g.V().hasLabel("entity").has("_id", "Test1").count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

Switched back to `inmemory` like [Kelvin Lawrence](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html) suggested earlier, since I'm not using large memory to get this concept down.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the examples from the [ref docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/) again:

- `JanusGraph` and `JanusGraphManagement` have independent transactions. Committing an index build is done with `mgmt.commit()`
- SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX and SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX are not explicitly called in the examples, these are implicit in the build call.

```js
graph.tx().rollback()  //Never create new indexes while a transaction is active
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
name = mgmt.getPropertyKey('name')
age = mgmt.getPropertyKey('age')
mgmt.buildIndex('nameAndAge', Vertex.class).addKey(name).addKey(age).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()
//Wait for the index to become available
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'nameAndAge').call()
//Reindex the existing data
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("nameAndAge"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
mgmt.commit()
```

Comment: Already tried this one and retried again. This still puts out warning even after I do the steps listed. This was my original try.

Comment: And as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213202/thought-i-created-a-janusgraph-vertex-index-but-i-guess-not-what-went-wrong)